# Getting a deb package from a repo without Debian

Tags: repository, deb

I've got this advice about where to get a certain package:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aleksandr-andreev/sci
```

I don't use Debian; I have some use for Debian packages, though. `ppa:aleksandr-andreev/sci` address is not recognized by a web browser, which is not a great surprise. Is there a way to check the contents of a given repository and find a package without employing the Debian infrastructure?

I can get a Debian/Ubuntu image into my Docker, of course, but this looks like a bit of an overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [search PPA repos here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) and transform the ppa URI as HTTP launchpad link like this: https://launchpad.net/~aleksandr-andreev/+archive/ubuntu/sci

Btw there is [already a **similar** answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178657/how-do-i-find-the-ppa-of-a-project-from-its-launchpad-page)